# Create pandas dfs in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'mandarin', 'kiwi', 'kiwi'], 'val':[1,5,3,4,5,3]})
```

I want to create seperate dataframes passing fruit name to the following function:

```
def split_all_fruits(df, fruit):
    return df[df['name'] == fruit]
```

Then I can create dataframes simply calling function:

```
apple_df = split_all_fruits(df, 'apple')
banana_df = split_all_fruits(df, 'banana')
#and other fruits
```

But I would like to create dataframes in for loop without calling funtion each time for each fruit. But is it possible to create for loop which results 5 dataframes with dataframe name from list for each fruit  at once?
Something like this:

```
#name of dfs
name_of_dfs = ['apple_df', 'banana_df', 'mandarin_df', 'kiwi_df']
#fruit names in df
fruit_name = ['apple', 'banana', 'mandarin', 'kiwi']
#loop to create dfs, but i dont know how to assign list of names in name_of_dfs to respective fruit df
for fruit in fruit_name:
    df_final = split_all_fruits(df,fruit)
    print(df_final)
#it prints all dfs together, but not seperate df with name from list
```

Thanks!

Comment: In these cases I use to create a dictionary. Key = name_of_df and value that dataframe.

`dict['name_i'] = dataframe_i`

Not sure if you can dynamically create variables, let see if anybody knows!
Cheers!

Comment: Do you want a single dataframe containing all the fruits or a list of dataframes with one fruit each?

Comment: Check [```eval```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval).

Comment: @alec_djinn in this case i want 5 seperate dataframe, where dataframe names are from the list : apple_df, banana_df, mandarin_df and kiwi_df. but i dont want to call function each and every time like this : `apple_df = split_all_fruits(df, 'apple')

banana_df = split_all_fruits(df, 'banana')` and other fruits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this could be done with `eval()` or `globals()`, a much better (cleaner, easier to manage programmatically) approach is to use a `dict` instead, e.g.:

```
dfs = {name: split_all_fruits(df, name) for name in fruit_name}
```

to be accessed as, e.g.:

```
dfs['apple']
```

---

## EDIT

If you *REALLY* want to have variables by the name of `apple_df` etc. one way of doing it is by modifying the `globals()` dictionary, e.g.:

```
globals().update({name + '_df': split_all_fruits(df, name) for name in fruit_name})
```

to be accessed as, e.g.:

```
apple_df
```

**Beware though that this is considered bad practice!**

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to generate a dataframe for each fruit, you could use the following (noting that the order will be alphabetical according to the fruit names):

```
[d for name, d in df.groupby("name")]
```

If you need a list in your specific order:

```
[df.query("name == '{}'".format(f)) for f in fruit_name]
```

If you wish to be able to access them by name, you could use a dictionary comprehension and reference the fruit name:

```
grouped = {name: d for name, d in df.groupby("name")}

# e.g. for apple:
apple_df = grouped['apple']
```

Finally, if you need to have the specific variables listed and know that these should be ahead of time:

```
grouped = {name: d for name, d in df.groupby("name")}

apple_df, banana_df, mandarin_df, kiwi_df = [grouped[fruit] for fruit in fruit_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want variable names instead of dictionary keys (not really a good idea but this was asked by the OP), you could use `exec()`.

```
#name of dfs
name_of_dfs = ['apple_df', 'banana_df', 'mandarin_df', 'kiwi_df']
fruit_name = ['apple', 'banana', 'mandarin', 'kiwi']

for fruit, df_name in zip(fruit_name, name_of_dfs):
    exec(f'{df_name} = split_all_fruits(df, "{fruit}")')
    print(globals()[df_name])
```

Now you can access the variable directly:

```
print(apple_df)

    name  val
0  apple    1
2  apple    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your last piece of code like below

```
name_of_dfs = ['apple_df', 'banana_df', 'mandarin_df', 'kiwi_df']
#fruit names in df
fruit_name = ['apple', 'banana', 'mandarin', 'kiwi']
dfs = {}
#loop to create dfs, but i dont know how to assign list of names in name_of_dfs to respective fruit df
for fruit in fruit_name:
    df_final = split_all_fruits(df,fruit)
    dfs[fruit] = df_final
    print(df_final)
```

Then, access any dataframe by using fruit name.

```
dfs['apple']
```